# an idiomatic way to initialize a Scala ArrayBuffer?

Tags: scala

I would like to initialize an `ArrayBuffer` with value -1 in indexes 0 through 99. Is there a simple, idiomatic way to do so?

This works, but it's a bit crufty:

```
val a = new ArrayBuffer&#91;Int&#93;()<br>
a.appendAll(Nil.padTo(100, -1))
```

I'd like to see something more like this:

```
val a = ArrayBuffer(List(-1) * 100)
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.fill(100)(-1)
```